# Two Table Returning Similar Data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I've tried every join i can think of but cant work it out :(

I have two tables

Table X and Table Y

Both tables contain Item Code and QTY

What i am looking for is something that can help me compare

Ideally i want to see something like this is it possible ?

example data
Table X

```
+-----------+-----+
| Item Code | QTY |
+-----------+-----+
| A         | 1   |
+-----------+-----+
| B         | 2   |
+-----------+-----+
| C         | 3   |
+-----------+-----+
```

Table Y

```
+-----------+-----+
| Item Code | QTY |
+-----------+-----+
| A         | 1   |
+-----------+-----+
| D         | 2   |
+-----------+-----+
| E         | 3   |
+-----------+-----+
```

End result i want to see something like this :

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| Item Code | TABLE X QTY | Table Y QTY |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| A         | 1           | 1           |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| B         | 2           | 0           |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| C         | 3           | 0           |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| D         | 0           | 2           |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
| E         | 0           | 3           |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+
```

is this even possible plz help

Comment: What query have you tried already?  You're probably closer than you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a `full join`

```
select coalesce(x.item, y.item) as item, 
       coalesce(x.qty, 0) as x_qty, coalesce(y.qty, 0) as y_qty
from x full join
     y
     on x.item = y.item
```

Comment: @JamesSmith . . . As a note, the *other* answer "also" works.  This answer was first.

Comment: apologies i thought the one closer to the top was first :(

Comment: @JamesSmith . . . I do not know how Stack Overflow orders answers.  However, just below the answer's grey box on the right (and above the name) is a time stamp.  If you mouse over the timestamp, you can see when the answer was created.  If it has been edited, there is an additional timestamp in the middle and the edit history (after the first five minutes) is available clicking on the link there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `full outer join`...

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(X.[Item Code],Y.[Item Code]) AS [Item Code],
    ISNULL(X.QTY,0) AS [TABLE X QTY],
    ISNULL(Y.QTY,0) AS [TABLE Y QTY]
FROM X
    FULL OUTER JOIN Y
        ON X.[Item Code] = Y.[Item Code]
```

Comment: @James... you're welcome. Although it is optional, please consider marking **one** of the answers as accepted - as that tells the community that your issue is solved